# sending json stored as string property of an object as JSON object to client

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am using cassandra as DB and storing user address as JSON in `"address"` field of `User` object.

```
class User {
  private long id;
  private String name;
  private String address;
}
```

Then the User row in DB columns as follows

```
id   |  name  |   address
================================
12345|  jhon  | {"hno":"12-10-46/3","street":"lavella road","city":"begaluru"}
```

But when I query `User` object from DB and returned as result of a REST api I see Jackson converting User object to JSON. But I observed that `"address"` field as string type instead of another JSON object. But I want that "address" should be interpreted as JSON object on client side.

How I could say jackson to convert internal string property to JSON as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use the annotation @JsonRawValue in your address field.

> @JsonRawValue: per-property marker that can be used to specify that
>   the value of property is to be included in serialization ''exactly''
>   as is, with no escaping or decoration -- useful for embedding
>   pre-serialized JSON (or whatever data format is being used) in output

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations

Comment: This also works for JSON included JSOn stored as String?

Answer (score 0):

It's being treated as a string because it is a string.  You'll need to convert it to an object.  Not being fluent in Java I managed to find this snippet that uses the javascript engine to eval the string into an object, the same as a browser would do:

```
 ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
 ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("js");        
 Object result = engine.eval([Your Address String Variable Here]);
```

And then **result** should be an object derived from the string.

Hope this helps.